# Rspec for Default Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

User model:

```
default_scope { where(:flg => '0') }
enum deleted_flg: { disabled: '1', enabled: '0' }
```

user spec:

```
describe 'default scope' do
  it 'returns deleted_flg' do
    user = build(:user, first_name: 'Test', flg: "0")
    expect(user.deleted_flg).to eq "enabled"
  end
end
```

I am not sure the specs I have written is correct or not for default scope.

Any help aprreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "default scope" is a macro (e.g. a filter or sort order) for all operations on the model.

If this is on a class called `User`, say, then you should expect to see this:

```
User.all # => SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted_flg = 0
```

You could test it by creating two or more records, then checking if `User.all` returns the expected record(s) in the expected order (if applicable). For example:

```
describe 'default scope' do
  it 'returns enabled users only' do
    enabled_user = create(:user, flg: '0')
    disabled_user = create(:user, flg: '1')
    expect(User.all).to eq [enabled_user]
  end
end
```

---

**Bonus:**

You're not using `enum` to its true potential! The *whole point* of it is that you can reference those numbers in a "human-friendly" way.

For example:

```
default_scope { where(flg: :enabled) }

# Or even:
default_scope { enabled }
```

And:

```
disabled_user = create(:user, flg: :disabled)
```

See [the documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for more.